# Avoid Multiple submits in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, transactions, django-forms

I am using auto submit in my forms.

Form gets automatically submitted when 10 digits are entered in the number field. This actually comes from USB RFID card reader upon scannig the card (It works as keyboard emulator).

I compare the number with the existing numbers in the database and then identify the user and perform some database transactions.

What happens is that the card reader reads the number multiple times, and due to that before all the database transactions complete for that input, another input is accepted (same number) within 1s and the consistency is lost before the first transaction is fully completed.

Kindly advise.

VIEWS.PY File:

```
@login_required
def markattdview(request):
    # for val in studmst.objects.filter(ccownerid=request.user.id)
# TO DOooo
    # select studid from attddetail where studentID= (select student ID from studmst where ccownerid = currentuser.ID)
    # lastattd=attddetail.objects.filter()
    # Showing last 10 users whose attendance have been marked by the logged in user
    #
    form_attd = markattdform()



    attdsuccess = ""
    identified_user = ""
    identified_studname=""
    loggedin_userid=request.user.id
    loggedinuser=request.user.username
    print("Logged in User : " + loggedinuser)

    if request.method == 'POST':
         studmstobj = studentmaster()

         attdform = markattdform(request.POST)
         unknown_cardno = request.POST.get('cardno')

         if attdform.is_valid():

                    #  form_attd.punchtime = datetime.datetime.now()
                    #  attdform.save(commit=True)


              obj = attdform.save(commit=False)
              obj.punchtime = datetime.datetime.now()
              attdsuccess = "Card not assigned. Kindly verify if the card has been registered."

              #studlist = studmst.objects.filter(ccownerid = request.user.id)
              #print (studlist[0])

#              for usr in studlist(cardnumber = obj.cardno):
# Identifying the user who swyped the card

              for usr in studentmaster.objects.filter(cardnumber = obj.cardno):
#WORKING FINE AFTER REMOVING WORKER AND REDISTOGO
#saving the details for identified User
                    identified_studname= usr.studentname
                    identified_cardno=usr.cardnumber
                    identified_studid = usr.studentid
                    punchdatetime=obj.punchtime
                    obj.studentname=identified_studname
                    obj.studentid_id=identified_studid
                    print('User Identified for card number  '+ identified_cardno)
                    print( "Identified user - " + identified_studname)
                    databasetransactions(identified_studid,identified_studname,punchdatetime)
```

JAVASCRIPT FOR AUTO FORM SUBMISSION:

```
$(function () {
  console.log(thetext);
    $('#thetext').bind('change keyup', function () {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 10) {
            $('#Form').submit();

        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add two variables: `formSubmitted` and `previousInput`. And every time the length of the text is > 10, I would check if the form was submitted and also if previous input is equal to the current input.

When you submit the form - you set the value of `formSubmitted` to `true`.

And in this case your form will be submitted if it wasn't submitted already, or if the previous input is different than the current one which means that another text was entered and it should also be submitted.

And finally on ajax success or error you set the formSubmited to false back to allow new form submitions.

Remember that your form will be also submited if the current input is different than the previous input!

```
$(function () {
    var formSubmitted = false;
    var previousInput = null;
    $('#thetext').bind('change keyup', function () {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 10 && (!formSubmitted || previousInput != $(this).val())) {
            var formData = new FormData($('#Form')[0]);

            previousInput = $(this).val();
            formSubmitted = true;
            $.ajax(
                url: '/endpoint.php',
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    formSubmitted = false;
                },
                error: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    formSubmitted = false;
                }
           });

        }
    })
});
```